# Solution to $ \sum (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \alpha_k = b_n$?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there anyone can tell me any information about the integer solution to the combinatotial equation 
$$
\sum (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \alpha_k = b_n
$$
(all variables are integers)?
For example,
suppose alpha_{0}=0 , when n=2, it is 2alpha_{1}-alpha_{1}=-b_{2} If we take b_{2} to be a given number, this is a first degree Diophantine Equation, we know how to solve it using elementary number theory, right? 
But when n=3, take b_{3} to be a given number, alpha_{0}=0, could you write down a general solution to this Dioph. equation?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly do you want? {n, 1} is 1, so alpha_1 is always uniquely determined by the other alpha_i.

Comment: a is a fixed integer and this is an equation about alpha_{k}?

Comment: Yes, so you can choose values of the other alpha_k, k > 0 arbitrarily and this determines the value of alpha_0 (which I'm sure is what darij meant to say).  Perhaps you meant to ask about a sequence a_n on the right?

Comment: Can you write down a general solution to this Diophantine Equation?

Comment: darij has already told you what the general solution is.   I really don't think you are asking the question you mean to ask.  

Comment: {n, k} is the binormal coefficient which is n choose k.
{n, 1} is n.

Comment: Ah, so it's a notation problem.  Mingming, {n, k} is often used to mean the number of partitions of an n-element set into k classes; so then {n, 1} = 1.  Use round brackets for binomial coefficients.

Comment: I read the problem as a sum from k = 0 to n and I read the brackets as binomial coefficients, so {n choose 0} = 1.  Also, {n choose n} = 1.  Either way, all but one of the alpha_i uniquely determines the last one, which is always an integer.  

Comment: Well, I've edited it now to reflect the questioner's apparent meaning.  To those reading this later: the original version used curly brackets around the n and k. 

Comment: (But I don't see any more sense in it than darij and Qiaochu.  Maybe the questioner can clarify his/her meaning.)

Comment: Dear Tom: When I write a to be a_{n} then there is a reciprocity between alpha_{k} and a_{n}.
I just want more information about this equation. 

Comment: mingming, I hope you can see that this is not the question you originally asked.

Answer (score 7):

I figured that's the question you wanted to ask.  The relation

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k} a_k = b_n$$

for all $n$ (you did not specify this; it was very unclear) is equivalent to the relation

$$e^{x} A(-x) = B(x)$$

where $A(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k, B(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{b_k}{k!} x^k$.  This gives $A(x) = e^x B(-x)$, or

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k} b_k = a_n.$$

So the $a_i$ are all integers if and only if the $b_i$ are all integers, and each uniquely determines the other.  I don't know what else to say; you can choose either the $a_i$ or the $b_i$ arbitrarily.  What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Suppose alpha_{0}=0 , when n=2, it is 2alpha_{1}-alpha_{1}=-b_{2}
If we take b_{2} to be a given number, this is a first degree Diophantine Equation, we know how to solve it using elementary number theory, right?
But when n=3, take b_{3} to be a given number, alpha_{0}=0, could you write down a general solution to this Dioph. equation?

Comment: You can use elementary number theory method to solve this three variable Dioph. equation. But when n turn out to be 4,5,6, how can we write down a general solution?

Comment: I hope the reciprocity formular will work here for bigger n.

Comment: Once more, mingming, that is not the question you originally asked.  My understanding of the question you are currently asking is that you can write down a general solution by repeated use of Bezout's lemma.

Comment: Dear Mr. Yuan:
Thank you very much.
Could you use Bezout Lemma to write down the solution for n=3?
I want to check it with my original solution.
Best!